# Maintaing show hide state of table after table reloads, using setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to achieve is, to have a series of tables built up with PHP (the number of tables is dynamic) this is reloaded every 5 seconds by using setInterval. Then be able to click on one of the tables to show or hide it. Ive got most of this working, but I have gotten stuck on maintaining the state of the tables, be they visible or hidden. Every time the table reloads the table state resets as its returning to its original state (I think a new reference is being passed, actually im almost certain thats whats happening). I tried copying the reference to the divs to a variable and comparing it to an old one (I took that bit of code out as it wasnt working) but I couldnt get the old settings into the new tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
        var divStateArray;
        function random_number() {
                var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*110000);
                return random;
        }
        //console.log(divStateArray);
        function reload(state){ 
                 $(".responsecontainer").load('counter.php?randval=' + random_number(), function() {
                                var $rowelements = $(".divRow");
                                var $divRow = $('.divTable').find($rowelements);        
                                        //console.log($divRow);
                                //by copying $divRow it copies a reference/pointer into divStateArray. 
                                //so any changes made to the properties of the div divRow are reflected in
                                //the afore mentioned variable. 
                                divStateArray = $divRow;

                                //merge the old settings in divoldstate with the new references in divStateArray
                                if (state == 'all') {
                                        divStateArray.hide();
                                }



                        }); 
        }
        //refresh the page every x miliseconds 
        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                                                        reload();                         
                                                }, 5000);


        $(document).ready(function() {
        //show the spinning logo until the tables are loaded. 
        $(".responsecontainer").html('<img src="/lbadmin/images/ajax-loader.gif" width=32 height=32 />');
        //display the page as soon as possible, then begin reloading every x seconds

        reload('all');
$(document).on('click',".headRow",function(){
                var $divRow = $(this).nextAll(".divRow")
                //console.log($divRow);
                if ($divRow.is(":hidden")) {
                       $divRow.show('fast');

                }                               
                else {
                       $divRow.hide('fast');
                }
        });

});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>hello</p>
<div class="responsecontainer" id="time1">
</div>
</br>
</body>
</html>
```

The table that gets loaded is (for the time being and for testing its just a static table but eventually this will change to multiple dynamic tables -

```
<?php
echo date("l, F d, Y h:i:s" ,time());
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />

<p>hello</p>
</br>
<div class="divTable">
        <div class="headRow">
                <div class="divCell">LABEL: vippoo</div>
                <div  class="divCell">IP: 192.168.67.505</div>
                <div  class="divCell">Ports: 80-81</div>
                <div  class="divCell">Method: Layer 4</div>
                <div  class="divCell">Mode: DR</div>
                <div  class="divCell">Protocol: TCP</div>
                <div  class="divCell">Graph: link</div>
        </div>


 <div class="divRow">
                        <div class="divCell">label1</div>
                        <div class="divCell">192.168.66.666</div>
                        <div class="divCell">1</div>
                        <div class="divCell">Drain</div>
                        <div class="divCell">Halt</div>
                        <div class="divCell">uparrow</div>
                        <div class="divCell">graphlink</div>
                </div>
 <div class="divRow">
                        <div class="divCell">label1</div>
                        <div class="divCell">192.168.66.666</div>
                        <div class="divCell">1</div>
                        <div class="divCell">Drain</div>
                        <div class="divCell">Halt</div>
                        <div class="divCell">uparrow</div>
                        <div class="divCell">graphlink</div>
                </div>
 <div class="divRow">
                        <div class="divCell">label1</div>
                        <div class="divCell">192.168.66.666</div>
                        <div class="divCell">1</div>
                        <div class="divCell">Drain</div>
                        <div class="divCell">Halt</div>
                        <div class="divCell">uparrow</div>
                        <div class="divCell">graphlink</div>
                </div>

</div>
</br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put a `<div>` around the table and show / hide that `<div>`? That way, if you reload the table, the visibility of the table remains the same as that is defined in the `div` around the table.

Comment: I dont know how many tables I am going to get, so for that to work, wouldnt I need to put the <div> in the main page? Would it be possible to do it with one div? so wrap all the tables in that <div> and that way the main page maintains a reference to the table itself?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply check the state of the table before trying the refresh/reload?

If the table is hidden don't perform the refresh then the state of the table will not change.

Your set-interval method can continue to loop and that's where (within) you would add your check.

So your `reload` becomes something like this

```
function isTableHidden() { 
    var $divRow = $('.divTable').nextAll(".divRow")
    return ($divRow.is(":hidden"))
}

function reload(state) { 

    if (isTableHidden())
        return; // exit early and don't reload anything

    $(".responsecontainer").load(
        ... rest of your oringal reload code ...
    );
}
```

Comment: That makes sense but I will have multiple tables and not all will be shown or hidden at the same time.

Comment: @MarcusMeeus ok so if you make one request for all tables perhaps you still need to do this - but only then when you try to refresh the table rows, perhaps ignore the ones that are hidden?

Comment: Otherwise just carry on with the solution i've provided in my answer